# Accessing Azure Storage services from a different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are looking to deploy our Azure cloud services to multiple subscriptions but want to be able to be able to access the same Storage accounts for storing blobs and tables. Wanted to know if it is possible to access storage accounts from across different subscriptions using just the storage account name and key? 
Our data connection takes the form

Trying to use the above and it always try to find end point for given accountname within the current subscription

Comment: I think you missed something in your question. A screenshot may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question...

> **able to access** the same Storage accounts

- Via **Azure Panel (Management Portal)** : you can access the storage account only in the subscription.
- Via **Visual Studio**: you can *attach* storage account outside your current login account in visual studio <-> azure with *account* name and *key* (and manage it)
  [image]
- Via **Code**: You can access storage account (blob, queue, table) from all your apps with storage connection strings (don't put it in code)

If you want, you can restrict blob access with CORS settings. Something like this :

```
  private static void InitializeCors()
    {
        ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();

        //Attiva e Configura CORS
        ConfigureCors(blobServiceProperties);

        //Setta
        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
    }

    private static void ConfigureCors(ServiceProperties prop)
    {
        var cors = new CorsRule();
        cors.AllowedOrigins.Add("www.domain1.net, www.domain2.it");
        prop.Cors.CorsRules.Add(cors);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! One minor comment though: You don't use CORS for restricting blob access. For restricting blob access, you use ACL, Access Policies and Shared Access Signature. CORS is used for allowing access to your storage account across domain (e.g. JavaScript AJAX calls to storage).

Comment: In my case, I want Azure Cognitive search to connect with Azure storage account in another subscription. How can this be done ?